# sequential autogenerated Id with help of linq

Tags: c#, linq, sequence, auto-generate

I have a class Booking

```
public class Booking
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string From { get; set; }

        public string To { get; set; }
    }
```

I create a List bookings with the help of linq and I want some mechanism with which I want to autogenerate the 'Id' property to increment by 1.

I.e. if the List bookings contains 10 Booking object then the first object's Id = 1, second Id = 2 and so one...

any suggestion

Comment: what do you mean by "I create a List bookings with the help of linq" ?

Comment: Your best bet is to let the database handle those unique ID's by specifying a "INT IDENTITY" column in your table to hold the bookings.

Comment: i dont have any database

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following will give you a list of NEW bookings with the index projected into your ID property.  You could probably do something similar to this to update the existing list with the index...

```
var myBookings = myExistingListOfTen.Select((b, index) => new Booking
                 {
                     Id = index + 1, 
                     From=b.From, 
                     To=b.To
                 });
```

Comment: This way you lose the reference and you do unnessecary object instantiation.

Comment: For me, this is the best answer so far.

Comment: True. But there are better solutions.

Comment: Yes, i agree there are too.  There are times when something like this can be used, but those cases are pretty small compared to when it probably shouldn't be used.

Comment: its looks good to me and can you give me equivalent of the above sample code in LINQ, i.e. 
from booking in Bookings
select new 
bla bla

Comment: My example is linq already.  To get the index, you have to use the overloads of the select methods - so no way to do that in the query based example without leaving the select in there.

Answer (score 6):

Not nice, but it will work. The trick is to use the overload providing the index of the item.

```
list = list.Select((item, index) => { item.Id = index; return item; });
```

This will update the existing bookings, but you could also select a new instance with the id set and avoid this ugly `return` at the cost of duplicating the bookings and losing the references as Scott Ivey suggests. And of course you have to add one if you want one-based ids.

I find it a bit strange to generate ids this way, too, but it might be a acceptable solution if you get a list of new bookings without id and want to generate them. In this case the ids should obviously not start with zero or one, but the largest already assigned id plus one.

Answer (score 4):

Surely if it is a property on the object you want the value to be consistent from invocation to invocation.  Booking 'A' shouldn't have a different id depending on where it exists in the list.  If you are simply wanting the index of the item in the list, don't store it as a property of the item, but derive it from its position in the list.

Comment: voted for this . all other suggestion do not take into account that bookings can be not only added but also removed from the collection. though, question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Booking
{
    private static int BookingCount = 1;

    public Booking()
    {
       Id = BookingCount++;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string From { get; set; }

    public string To { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is bad practice, ins't it? What is the questioner wants two collections?

Comment: this will create a global counter... and also, i will suggest using Interlocked for thread safety

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question right, but you could always

```
ID = bookings.Select(b=>b.ID).Max()+1;
```

Not sure if that's such a good idea (it won't be uber performant).

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @tvanfosson (+1), if you really want to keep an `ID` in `Booking` I think that this should be setted upon the construction of Booking. You could have something like a Booking Context where each context would create bookings with serial IDs:

```
    public class Booking
    {
        protected Booking() { }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string From { get; set; }

        public string To { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookingContextFactory
    {
        private int count;

        public BookingContextFactory() : this(0) { }
        public BookingContextFactory(int startValue) 
        {
            count = startValue;
        }

        public Booking CreateBooking(string from, string to)
        {
            return new InternalBooking { Id = count++, From = from, To = to };
        }

        private class InternalBooking : Booking
        {
            public InternalBooking() : base() { }
        }
    }
```